# android imagebutton can not show ,layout file is following

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" 
        android:paddingTop="500dp">

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id_button_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/previous"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id_button_startpause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_button_previous"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/startstop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_startpause" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/id_button_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_button_startpause"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_next"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>  


</LinearLayout>
```

The layout can show textview 'helloworld',but couldn't show imageButton,

I don't know why it couldn't show normally,where is the error. if I don't write more ,
I can't submmit,this is useless.By the way ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, such a big padding,

```
android:paddingTop="500dp"
```

In here,

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" 
        android:paddingTop="500dp">
```

Remove the padding or resize the padding of your reative layout to smaller value.
Something like,

```
android:paddingTop="50dp"
```

Modified code,

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" 
        android:paddingTop="50dp">
```

And it works, you will see your images..

Comment: he might be developing for TV :P

Comment: padding means  the  space between RelativeLayout part with external linearLayout?

Comment: I want the padding value to be 200dp,what should  I do ? paddingTop is\ internal RelativeLayout

Comment: make the height of TextView to wrap content and change the padding from 500dp tp 200dp

Comment: you may not understand my question. if I do like you say,the padding space between RelativeLayout and external linearLayout would never change,the change will appear in internal of RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

just remove the

```
android:paddingTop="500dp"
```

from your relative layout and they'll work =)

Comment: please accept the answer ( the tick ) if it helped you, and welcome to stackoverflow !

Answer (score 0):

your layout is wrong you have given the relative layout a pading of 500dp so the image button are 500dp below and since there is no scroll view added in the layout you cannot see your image buttons

Comment: padding means the space between RelativeLayout part with external linearLayout?

Comment: no padding means the area left before the content starts or you can say its the margin for all the child views in the layout and if you want your relative layout to be 500dp below the text view then you should give android:marginTop = "500dp" in the relative layout and then you should put the whole layout inside a scroll view so you can actually see your image buttons which will be 500do below text view

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this....

```
android:paddingTop="500dp"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id_button_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/previous"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_previous"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id_button_startpause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/startstop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_startpause" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/id_button_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_next"
            />

    </LinearLayout>  


</LinearLayout>
```